# How can I make Apache Solr Autocomplete work in search Views?

Tags: views, search, ajax

I'm trying to work with Apache Solr search in my view and make this autocomplete.

Apache solr is configured correctly and I've added a solr view. I can search on fields, that's no problem. But how can I make the autocomplete work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to search in google? before asking. Have you tried to do anything?
 I noticed you're constantly asking questions to which the answer can be found by spending a little time searching.
Try to do something by yourself before asking. thanks.

[ApacheSolr Autocomplete module](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_autocomplete) - This module should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm working with that module but documentation is very poor.